# round image for tableview cell

Tags: uitableview, ios7, rounding, iphone-5

I have searched several places but couldn't find an appropriate answer. I have a tableview with text and image. But the image size should be a small rounded image (not round corners but perfect circular image) of fixed size for all the cells. Just like the current whatsapp one. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following code

```
 yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageHeight/2;
 yourImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

This would give you an round image.

Comment: Just to mention that the `imageHeight` is gonna be same as the `imageWidth` as it is a circle being inscribed inside something you can call a square.

Comment: And don't forget to import the required `QuartzCore` library

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, my image height is diff as width, its kind of a rectangle

Comment: Even if it's a rectangle the longer side would have to be reduced to be equal to the shorter one as a circle can be inscribed in a square only (if you inscribe a circle in a rectangle, it would be the same as inscribing it in a square of side equal to the smaller side of the rectangle)